# Custom script stops at require_once

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My custom script simply stops running when i include wc-order-functions.php

It prints test1 and test2 but test3 doesn't appear.

This is part of my script

```
<?php
echo 'test1';
set_time_limit(3000);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
umask(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo 'test2';
require_once('../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-order-functions.php');

echo 'test3';
```

Comment: Is there an `exit;` or `die()` in that script?

Comment: No, my script doesn't have an exit or die @Qirel

Comment: your path is probably wrong. did you even bother to check your error_log ?

Comment: @delboy1978uk yes, i checked it. it is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at that code in Github, presuming it's the same code, one of the first lines is this:

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
```

This means that if the constant `ABSPATH` is not defined, the code will exit. Is that constant defined somewhere in your code that you haven't shown?  If not, it's exiting before your third echo.

Comment: I just spotted that myself. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-order-functions.php

Comment: @droopssnoot @delboy1978uk I added the define for ABSPATH but now i get this error `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_formatted_shipping_address() on bool in /home1/camarelo/public_html/curier/fancourier.php on line 28` when trying to use 

     $id_comanda = $_GET['order_id'];
     $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
     $address = $order->get_formatted_shipping_address();

Comment: That suggests that your `$order` variable has come back with the value of false from your `wc_get_order()` call, so you need to find out why. Where does your `$order_id` variable come from? Shouldn't that be `$id_comanda`?